# HPE Switch "Software caused connection abort"

Tags: switch, hp, hp-procurve

I have a stacked HPE 2920 switches which have two vlan-interfaces (VLANs 200 and 96):

```
vlan 96
 name "mgmt"
 untagged 1/1,2/1
 tagged 1/48,Trk1-Trk5
 ip address 192.168.96.20 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.200.200.26
 exit
vlan 200
 name "inside"
 untagged 1/2-1/36,2/2-2/36
 tagged 1/48,Trk1-Trk5
 ip address 10.200.200.150 255.255.0.0
 exit
```

Pings will be answered on both IP-Addresses. But the SSH Connetion only works on the VLAN 200.
I get the following error message on the VLAN 96 IP-Address:

> Network error: Software caused connection abort

No ACL are set on the switch.

Have someone an idea where could be the issue?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, that could be the problem with SSH client software. Try with another SSH client program or from a Linux box. Were you ever able to ssh to that switch on VLAN 96 IP_address before? Also, try to test by telneting to 192.168.96.20 (VLAN 96) on port 22.

Comment: Depending on the routes on that switch, it is quite common that SSH only works from the 'correct' side, ie. you may not be able to SSH to 192.168.96.20 from 10.200.0.0/16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. I missed the forest before the trees.

A second interface had an IP Address in the same Subnet. Of course SSH was only allow on the same subnet

After I removed the IP address from the VLAN 200 the SSH access from VLAN 96 worked.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: I will do it, but have to wait:
"You can accept your own answer in  16 hours"